# Converting xcode project to dylib

Tags: xcode, project, dylib

I want to create a .dylib file. I have a iPhone project in XCode. Is there any way this project can be converted to a .dylib file? Can anyone please give me detailed step by step instructions. I do not want to create dylib file in C language. I heard there are some templates to create, but there is no proper tutorial found.

Comment: What type of project is it at the moment; a static library?

Comment: yes.. it is a static library..

Answer (score 0):

Xcode does not natively support building dylibs for iOS. Try hacking the Xcode config to add this support as described here: http://blog.iosplace.com/?p=33

Comment: I am able to create a dynamic library but when I use it along with the  an application the application crashes. Does anyone have a sample dylib for IOS?

Comment: Also, how are you integrating it with the app? Linking in Xcode in Build settings?